# Integral of $\cos\left(\frac1x\right)\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is the following integral expression correct (neglecting the constant of integration)?

$$
\int\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx = x^2\sin\left(2x\right)
$$

When I take the derivative, it returns to the integral, so it's ok, right? For some reason I can't find this integral over the internet, and Wolfram gives a strange answer.

Comment: it returns to the integrand*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us check by differentiating your claimed antiderivative.

Call $F(x) = x^2 \sin(2x)$. Then $F'(x) = 2x\sin(2x) + 2x^2\cos(2x)$. Now we ask, is $F'(x)$ the same as $\cos(1/x)$?

Although there are many ways to understand it, they are not the same. For instance, $\cos(1/x)$ is bounded by $1$ always, while $F'(\pi)$ is much larger.

So they are not the same. In fact, $\displaystyle \int \cos(1/x) dx$ has no elementary antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int\cos\dfrac{1}{x}~dx
&=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{-2n}}{(2n)!}~dx\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{1-2n}}{(2n)!(1-2n)}+C\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!(2n-1)x^{2n-1}}+C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \cos(1/x)dx = \frac{2x \cos(1/x) - i \cdot \Gamma(0, \frac{i}{x}) + i \cdot \Gamma(0, -\frac{i}{x})}{2}+C$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} x^2\sin(2x)=2x\sin(2x)+2x^2\cos(2x)$$